# My Adobe XD plugin isn't making any changes to the document

Tags: plugins, adobe-xd

I'm writing a plugin for Adobe XD, and it has stopped making changes to the document for some reason.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plugins cause an error, any changes made during that edit operation are *rolled back*. Plugin actions are atomic – failure will revert the entire operation. That may be why you're not seeing any changes.

## Debugging plugins

You can use the XD Developer Console to check for errors and debug. The Developer Console is in the app menu at:

> *Plugins > Development > Developer Console*

## Reloading development plugins

If you make any edits to your code, be sure to reload all plugins in the `develop` folder:

> *Plugins > Development > Reload Plugins*

---

There's a tutorial in the XD plugin API docs with [tips on debugging plugins](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/tutorials/debugging/).